# Triple handshake (TLS) EMS protection against attacks

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, tls-intercept

In TLS we have such an extension as EMS (extended master secret).

It has been applied to protect the master secret. But I don't understand how it helps against triple handshake attack.

I assume that attacker can use two master secrets (one with client, second with server). So attacker can read all messages.

Where is my mistake? (because it must help in protection against this triple handshake attack)

Comment: *"I assume that attacker can use two master secrets"* - The very idea of the triple handshake attack is that the attacker controls the master secret between client and server by being part of an earlier (later resumed) handshake and making sure that the master secrets are the same. Therefore the missing understanding of how EMS helps results from the missing understanding of what the triple handshake attack is. So please study [the description of the attack](https://mitls.org/pages/attacks/3SHAKE) more carefully.